# How to forbid for users to follow the exactly URL link?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to forbid or redirect the users to 404 page or to home page if they want to enter to specific link.

For example, user tries to go to `mywebsite.com/?=some_link&some_name`

I have removed this hyperlink from HTML code, but also I want to redirect all users who already know this link and try to visit it directly.

Is it possible to solve it with .htaccess?

Comment: possible duplicate of [.htaccess - 404 error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10267879/htaccess-404-error)

Comment: Can you specify the exact link leaving the domain name `mywebsite.com` and not just bogus `/?=some_link&some_name`?

Answer (score 0):

Well simply if the page doesn't actually exist anymore you can just use an `ErrorDocument` directive and Apache will do that for you. It can go at the top of you .htaccess file.

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404page.html
```

Or you can redirect the specific request for it

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} [A-Z]{3,}\ /+\?some_link&some_name
RewriteRule ^ / [R=301,L]
```